# ADB disconnect while using adb forward

Tags: adb, tethering

I'm using [JADS HTTP & HTTPS Proxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.jads.android.proxy) application along with 'adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080' to setup an HTTP proxy/tether setup on my laptop.  This works fine for most of the time, however some sites seem to overload the connection and the device goes offline, then back online, and my adb forward command has to be re-issued.  I've tried changing the number of connections in about:config in Firefox thinking that was the issue but it doesn't seem to help.

Here's my logcat of a disconnect when trying to connect to drive.google.com:

```
I/System.out(22946): Connection from /127.0.0.1 accepted.
I/System.out(22946): Connection from /127.0.0.1 accepted.
I/System.out(22946): Connection from /127.0.0.1 accepted.
I/System.out(22946): 127.0.0.1 CONNECT lh4.googleusercontent.com:443
I/System.out(22946): Connecting to
lh4.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
I/System.out(22946): 127.0.0.1 CONNECT lh3.googleusercontent.com:443
I/System.out(22946): Connecting to
lh3.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
I/System.out(22946): Routing SSL to
lh3.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
I/System.out(22946): Routing SSL to
lh4.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
I/System.out(22946): 127.0.0.1 CONNECT lh5.googleusercontent.com:443
I/System.out(22946): Connecting to
lh5.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: iptype =3
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: query_ipv4=1, query_ipv6=1
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: iptype =3
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: query_ipv4=1, query_ipv6=1
I/System.out(22946): Routing SSL to
lh5.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: iptype =3
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: query_ipv4=1, query_ipv6=1
I/System.out(22946): Connection from /127.0.0.1 accepted.
I/System.out(22946): 127.0.0.1 CONNECT lh6.googleusercontent.com:443
I/System.out(22946): Connecting to
lh6.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
I/System.out(22946): Routing SSL to
lh6.googleusercontent.com:443[Protocol=HTTPS, Priority=1]
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: iptype =3
D/libc    (  270): _dns_getaddrinfo: query_ipv4=1, query_ipv6=1
```

At this point the device disconnects and reconnects to ADB (it vibrates).  Logcat continues:

```
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to www.gstatic.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to clients2.google.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to apis.google.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to plus.google.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to lh4.googleusercontent.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to lh5.googleusercontent.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to lh6.googleusercontent.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to ssl.gstatic.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to www.google.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to lh3.googleusercontent.com
I/System.out(22946): Closed connection to drive.google.com
D/qcom_sensors_hal( 1079): hal_time_data_cb: msg_type 2
D/qcom_sensors_hal( 1079): hal_time_data_cb: Sn 24, msg Id 3, txn Id 0
D/qcom_sensors_hal( 1079): hal_ts_offset_is: Apps:
1415721384416465123; DSPS: 596345578; Offset: 1415703185393699010
I/Atd     (  565): got usb DISCONNECTED event 
I/Atd     (  565): ustate is ATD_USBSTATE_UNPLUG
I/Vold    (  264): [LGE][VOLD][NetlinkHandler.cpp][onEvent()]
subsys:android_usb, action:3
```

I'm running the latest version of Adb.exe with AdbWinApi.dll and AdbWinUsbApi.dll (all dated 10/17/2014 7:36pm).  I've tried other version of Adb without any success.  The phone is LG G2 model and the machine has the LG Unified Mobile Driver on it to recognize the phone when connected.  I'm running Android v4.4.2.  I've tried all the USB ports on my laptop and all of them are doing the same thing.  I tried on a desktop computer as well, multiple ports and I was able to reproduce it (the disconnect on certain sites).

I've tried [Tetherbot](http://graham.ms/androidproxy/) and [Internet Sharer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.jads.android.netsharer) as well and they also do the same thing (disconnect).  I don't remember having this issue with my old EVO LTE however.

Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I may have stumbled upon the fix for this.  I was looking through about:config for Firefox and noticed a [network.http.pipelining.maxrequests](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.pipelining.maxrequests) variable.  Althought it's set to false by default for ssl and proxy, lowering the value to 1 seems to have completely resolved my issue.  I set it back to it's default (32) and the issue happened again.  Lowered to 1, and again page loaded without ADB being disconnected.  This seems to be a bug in Firefox.  I'm running the latest version 33.1.